# general form of group elements of the symplectic group

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

For the unitary group $U(n)$, its group elements are of the form $e^{iH}$, with $H$ being a $n\times n $ hermitian matrix.

Do we have a similar expression for the group element of the symplectic group $Sp(2n,\mathbb{C})$? The group is defined as

$$ Sp(2n,\mathbb{C}) =\{ A \in M_{2n\times 2n } (\mathbb{C}),    A \Omega A^T = \Omega  \}, $$

where $\Omega$ is defined as

$$ \Omega = 
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
    0 & I_n \\
    -I_n & 0  \end{array} \right) . $$

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051255/is-the-exponential-map-for-textsp2n-mathbb-r-surjective). The exponential map is not surjective, but still we have $\text{Sp}_{2n}({\mathbb R})=\text{exp}({\mathfrak s}{\mathfrak p}_{2n}({\mathbb R}))^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we have $A = e^B \in \mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$, with $B \in \mathfrak{sp}(2n,\mathbb{C}) = \{M \in \mathrm{Mat}(2n,\mathbb{C}) \;|\; \Omega M + M^T \Omega = 0\}$, the latter being the Lie algebra associated to the Lie group of complex symplectic matrices.